# What tag libraries you know for Java EE JSP, something like displaytag, tinyMCE, and other useful stuff for new J2EE Developer?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tinymce, displaytag

What tag libraries you know for Java EE JSP, something like [displaytag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/), [tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), and other useful stuff for new Java EE Developer.

Comment: There is no single answer to this question. Should be community wiki IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned my favorite: displaytag. I also use the Struts tags for their html tag set.

Answer (score 0):

I like to pair ajax-tags:display to wrap my displaytags to get some ajax work done.